# Python Pandas Drop Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How do I delete a column from a DataFrame? I know this data is not reproducible as I have a CSV file and I am trying to build a pandas data frame to do some wrangling.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\LoadProfiles\CSV\WillBaySchl 2013_2014 KW.csv')

print(df)
```

This will return the head/tail and:`[34944 rows x 3 columns]`

```
pos0 = 0
pos1 = 1
pos2 = 2

colname = df.columns[pos0]
print(colname)
```

This will return: `Meter ID` (I want to drop this column/dataframe)

```
colname = df.columns[pos1]
print(colname)
```

This will return: `Date / Time` (I want this to be the pd data frame index)

```
colname = df.columns[pos2]
print(colname)
```

This will return: `KW(ch: 1  set:0)` (This is the data that I want to rename "kW" and do some wrangling...)

If I try this code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.drop(['Meter ID'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Python will return the error:`TypeError: drop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'`

If I try this code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.drop(columns=['Meter ID'])
print(df)
```

Python will return the error: `TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: You probably have a pandas pre- 0.21, where the columns kw was introduced. Check your version and use `labels`, coupled with `axis=1` instead.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.drop(['Meter ID'], axis=1)` you are calling the method on the DataFrame constructor so it thinks the first positional argument is `self`. Use it on an instance (for example `df`).

Comment: Can reiterate what you mean by `self`? I don't understand how to put this to use with Pandas.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question , what i understand is you wanted to drop column `['Meter ID']` available in your `df = pd.read_csv('C:\LoadProfiles\CSV\WillBaySchl 2013_2014 KW.csv')` pandas dataframe .
I am assuming that you have column name `['Meter ID']` like these in your dataframe and also as header in your csv file .

```
>>> df.dtypes
Meter ID           int64
someothercolumn    int64
dtype: object
```

for that you can simply use these code ,

```
del df['Meter ID']
```

Now if you wanted to delete overall dataframe you can simply use these code,

```
df=None
```

Answer (score 12):

If I understand right to delete column (single) you should use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.drop('Meter ID', axis=1)
```

For more than 1 column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.drop(['Meter ID', 'abc'], axis=1)
```

Difference is in [] brackets.

To delete the whole df you can use either (as mentioned already):

```
del df
```

or

```
df = None
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop a column from dataframe,

```
df = df.drop('Meter ID', axis=1)
```

Drop more than one columns at a time,

```
df = df.drop(['Meter ID', 'SomethingElse'], axis=1)
```

For more [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Answer (score 0):

To lose the 'Meter ID' column you could also use:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Meter ID'])
```

post pandas version 0.21